# Class is not assignable from interface

Tags: c#

**Overwiew**

(question is at the end)

In my application, I have a following classes and interfaces (simplified):

```C#
class RequestingUserData
interface IQuery<TResult>
interface IQueryWithUser<TResult> : IQuery<TResult>
class UserSearchQuery : IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>

interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> 
{ 
    TResult Handle(TQuery);
}
interface IUserSearchQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery, RequestingUserData>
class UserSearchQueryHandler : IUserSearchQueryHandler
```

I would like to cast `UserSearchQueryHandler` onto it's "highest" interface - `IQueryHandler` like so :

```
(IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>,RequestingUserData>)new UserSearchQueryHandler();
```

but this will result in runtime casting exception.

**Problem**

```C#
var assignable = typeof(IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>,RequestingUserData>)
.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UserSearchQueryHandler))`
```

returns false.

However, when I do this:

```C#
typeof(IQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery,RequestingUserData>)
.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UserSearchQueryHandler))
```

it is obviously true.

**What I tried**

I tried to rearrange my definitions:

```
interface IUserSearchQueryHandler<T> : IQueryHandler<T, RequestingUserData> where T : IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData> 
class UserSearchQueryHandler : IUserSearchQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery>
```

but it did not help.

**Question**

Is there any possibility to convert/cast object of `UserSearchQueryHandler` to `IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>,RequestingUserData>` ?

**EDIT**

This is actually what I intent to do with my casting (simplified):

```
public async Task<K> Dispatch<K>(IQueryWithUser<K> query)
{
  return await DoDispatchWithUser<IQueryWithUser<K>, K>(query);
}
// below T will be IQueryWithUser<K>
private async Task<K> DoDispatchWithUser<T, K>(T query) where T : class, IQueryWithUser<K>
{
  var handler = ResolveHandler(query) as IQueryHandler<T, K>; // Becomes null 
  return await DispatchCommand(handler, query); 
}
 private async Task<K> DispatchCommand<T, K>(IQueryHandler<T, K> handler, T query) where T : class, IQuery<K>
{
  return await handler.Handle(query);
}
 private object ResolveHandler<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
{
  var handler = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
  var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(handler); // this returns UserSearchQueryHandler object
  return service;
}
```

Comment: But the class doesn't implement `IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>,RequestingUserData>`, it implements `IQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery, RequestingUserData`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that is true but why it is not the case that when `UserSearchQuery` implements `IQueryWithUser<>` I can exchange between those types?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I think I see OP's point though. `UserSearchQuery` is an implementation of `IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>`, which in turn is an implementation of `IQuery<RequestingUserData>`. Since a derivation/implementation should always be able to be cast down towards its base class/interface (including multiple levels of inheritance/implementation), `UserSearchQuery` should be usable in a place where `IQuery<RequestingUserData>` is expected.

Comment: That's simply not how generics and inheritance works.

Comment: The problem here is that `Type<DerivedType>` does not inherit from `Type<BaseType>` because the inheritance is on the `Type<T>` level, not on the `T` level.

Comment: @Flater I have no problem seeing OP's point but unfortunately wishing it were true doesn't make it so. There are existing duplicates for this kind of question here on stack overflow though I'm unable to find them right now.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen your answer makes much sense, I will need to find some other solution then. Do you suggest that I should remove this questions since it is a duplicate?

Comment: You can try `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))` vs. `typeof(List<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<string>))`.

Comment: To perform this cast, you need to have this definition: `IQueryHandler<out TQuery, TResult>`. With current (`in TQuery`) - that will not work.

Comment: @Evk this would be great solution if I was able to do TQuery as output type (updated my question).

Comment: Yes I understand. In your case it's not possible to do that cast, because after cast you are able to pass any `IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>` to `Handle` fuction, but original type (`UserSearchQueryHandler`) accepts only one implementation (`UserSearchQuery`). So doing this is not type-safe and so is not allowed.

Comment: Question is: what are you actually going to do after performing this cast? You cannot reliably call `Handle` anyway, so what else?

Comment: @Evk updated my question with code that I intend to use